# Getting error when when I call the shap.plots.waterfall() function

Tags: python, shap

I am getting an error when running the `shap.plots.waterfall()` as shown below:

`Exception: waterfall_plot requires a scalar base_values of the model output as the first parameter, but you have passed an array as the first parameter! Try shap.waterfall_plot(explainer.base_values[0], values[0], X[0]) or for multi-output models try shap.waterfall_plot(explainer.base_values[0], values[0][0], X[0]).`

Below my code:

```
import shap
explainer   = shap.Explainer(model)
shap_values = explainer(X_train)
shap.plots.waterfall(shap_values)
```

I was able to get the bar plot working using the code below but not the waterfall function.
`shap.summary_plot(shap_values, X_train,feature_names = YE_x.columns.values.tolist(), plot_type="bar")`

I greatly appreciate the help!

Comment: I would suggest `print`ing `shap_values` and checking it's the right type (scalar not array).

Answer (score 0):

Like the error is saying, and the [documentation](https://shap.readthedocs.io/en/latest/example_notebooks/api_examples/plots/waterfall.html)

> Waterfall plots are designed to display explanations for individual predictions, so they expect a single row of an Explanation object as input.

You can write something like this:

```
import shap
explainer   = shap.Explainer(model)
shap_values = explainer(X_train)
shap.plots.waterfall(shap_values[1]) # or any random value
```

Comment: Hi! I tried that but i get this error:                                                      
```Exception: waterfall_plot requires a scalar base_values of the model output as the first parameter, but you have passed an array as the first parameter! Try shap.waterfall_plot(explainer.base_values[0], values[0], X[0]) or for multi-output models try shap.waterfall_plot(explainer.base_values[0], values[0][0], X[0]).```

Answer (score 0):

print out your shap_values[0]
you want to see a scalar value under base_value
something like .base_values = 0.26918828
if you see an array, that's your problem

are you using a XGBClassifier or a XGBRegressor? because that might be your problem